# How do I create an update button using JComboBox dropdown list in netbeans 8.2?

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to create an update button for a dropdown list that gets the data from the database in the netbeans. Tried this method below but couldn't get it to work. Any suggestions? Thanks alot.

```
public class ViewProduct extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 ResultSet rs;
 PreparedStatement pst;
 Connection conn;    
 final void FillList(){
 try{   
        //establish connection to table
        String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ProductInformation";
        String username = "admin1";
        String password = "admin1";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        // get data from table in sql database
        String Query = "SELECT * FROM VIEWPRODUCT";
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(Query);
        //
        DefaultListModel DLM = new DefaultListModel();

        while(rs.next()){

        JList list = new JList();
        JComboBox ProductID_dropdown = new JComboBox();
        DefaultComboBoxModel listModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

        list.setModel(listModel);
        ProductID_dropdown.setModel(listModel);
        }

}catch(SQLException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
}
```

Comment: Your code is a bit off, you seem to create lots and lots of new(!) `JComboBoxes` in your `while(rs.next())`-Loop. You actually want to create only one `JComboBox` and then fill it in your loop. Then you add a single update Button and an `ActionListener`.

Comment: How do you actually add an ActionListener within the FillList() itself?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things not right or missing in your code. For instance you have no GUI.

And as I dont know the exact structure of your project or your database, I have to improvise and give you a pseudo-code approach.
You will have to change and configure several things I am showing here.

First, create a JComboBox outside of your method and add it to a container like JPanel:

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
JComboBox productID_dropdown = new JComboBox();
JButton btn_updateViewProducts = new JButton("Update Results");
```

Here the Button for updating your results is added, it contains an `ActionListener`, that "listens" to when someone is clicking on the button.
Usually you want to retrieve a `ResultSet` and put its contents into variables, like in [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html):

```
// ActionListener for the button
btn_updateViewProducts.add(new ActionListener{
    @Override
    // When the button is clicked...
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // ... get the results out of your database (here it's an example database! 
        // Configure for your own one)
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(Query);
        while(rs.next()){
            // "de-construct" every result of the ResultList into variables
            String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " + "SALES, TOTAL " + "from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";
            String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
            int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
            float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
            int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
            int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
            System.out.println(coffeeName + "\t" + supplierID + "\t" + price + "\t" + sales + "\t" + total);

            // Put items into JComboBox
            productID_dropdown.addItem(coffeeName);
        }        
    }
});

// Add the now filled JComboBox to the pane
pane.add(productID_dropdown);
```

Other issues you should think about:

- GUI is missing
- the method `FillList` is final, which seems unusual, any reason behind this? `final` in a method means, that it cant be overridden by subclasses, it this needed here?
- `FillList` is a method and should be written with a small letter at the start due to coding convention, the same goes for `ProductID_dropdown` (coding convention)
- most of the time it's quite okay to use short variables like `rs` for a `ResultSet`, but if your projects get bigger, it gets harder to keep all those variables in mind. Better: make them tell you, what they are. Instead of `rs` -> `resultSetViewProduct` or similar.
- `PreparedStatement pst` is never used

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I found another solution which makes the update button work in the JFrame form. Thanks for the help!